# Ng-Table ng-repeat on nested values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I have this list i wanted to display on ng-table.

```
$scope.list = [
    {
        "moduleId": 1,
        "name": "Perancangan",
        "level": 0,
        "childs": [
            {
                "moduleId": 12,
                "name": "Perancangan Sektor",
                "level": 1,
                "childs": [],
                "links": [
                    {
                        "rel": "self",
                        "href": "http://103.8.160.34/mrf/modules/1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "moduleId": 2,
        "name": "Pengurusan Pengguna dan Peranan",
        "level": 0,
        "childs": [
            {
                "moduleId": 17,
                "name": "Pengurusan Pengguna",
                "level": 1,
                "childs": [],
                "links": []
            },
            {
                "moduleId": 18,
                "name": "Operasi Peranan",
                "level": 1,
                "childs": [],
                "links": []
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://103.8.160.34/mrf/modules/2"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I wanted the list.childs to be the rows in the table with the list.name as grouping, i'd used ng-repeat to  but doesn't work. The most i could do is display it as td. What im looking at is

```
    
    Perancangan (header)
       Perancangan Sektor 
       Pengurusan Pengguna dan Peranan
```

Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/77t5id3WOmbl2GSqYKh2?p=preview

Comment: So you only need Perancangan as the header and the rest as the child? Not the name for every object in the list to be the header?

Comment: Yes.Currently just needed list[name] as the header

Comment: So, list is an array of objects. You have two objects right now in the array. I guess what you want is, for every object in the list, make the name as the header and the childs of that object as the children. Right?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: This is much doable using ul than table.

Comment: Yes. But i need it to be in table because i want to put checkboxes on every child rows

Comment: You can still use ul for the header and input checkboxes as the child

Comment: yeah, you shouldn't be using a table for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be at least two ways you could accomplish this. The first might be more simple but skirts the question you posed. Massage the list[] into a flattened and simplified array tailored for this table's view. You would then ng-repeat over that array.

That is really a dodge though and completely avoids your question. More directly to your question you could try to use nested ng-repeat's but those are pretty tricky. See: http://vanderwijk.info/blog/nesting-ng-repeat-start/

Finally, the approach that seems to best address you're question in both intent and spirit is to use a custom filter. I've written an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnash21/xjt97qb6/) that should demonstrate the idea.

```
app.filter('flatten', function() {

// Because this filter is to be used for an ng-repeat the filter function
// must return a function which accepts an entire list and then returns
// a list of filtered items.
return function(listItems) {
    var i,j;
    var item, child;
    var newItem;
    var flatList = [];

    // Begin a loop over the entire list of items provided by ng-repeat
    for (i=0; i<listItems.length; i++) {
        var item = listItems[i];

        // Construct a new object which contains just the information needed
        // to display the table in the desired way. This means we just extract
        // the list item's name and level properties
        newItem = {};
        newItem.name = item.name.toUpperCase();
        newItem.level = item.level;

        // Push the level 0 item onto the flattened array
        flatList.push(newItem);

        // Now loop over the children. Note that this could be recursive
        // but the example you provided only had children and no grandchildren
        for (j=0; j<item.childs.length; j++) {
            child = item.childs[j];

            // Again create a new object for the child's data to display in
            // the table. It also has just the name and level.
            newItem = {};
            newItem.name = child.name;
            newItem.level = child.level;

            flatList.push(newItem);
        }
    }

    // Return the newly generated array that contains the data which ng-repeat
    // will iterate over.
    return flatList;
};
});
```

Comment: Thank You. I use the flatten and write a filter for it.